# Should I use hstore in renewed data model?

Tags: postgresql, hstore

In my legacy database (Postgres 9.1) I have several tables containing divers kinds of documents (let's say they are 'parent' tables).
Additionally, there is a table with various parameters for these documents:

```
create table params (
    kind integer,
    docid integer,
    parname text,
    parvalue text,
    constraint params_pk primary key (kind, docid, parname));
```

There may be many *(parname, parvalue)* pairs for one document.
As *kind* points to different tables it cannot be used as a foreign key.

It has been working well for years as *params* were used only for printing documents. 
Now this table contains 5 millions rows and the data is needed also for other purposes.
So it is high time to renew this model.

Basically *params* are inserted once for a document and very seldom updated. They will be read as a whole (for a document). There is no need to search for a specific *parname*.

I have three ideas:

Variant A.
Split table *params* into several tables according to parent tables and use *docid* as foreign key.

Variant B.
Split table *params* as in variant A and store *(parname, parvalue)* as hstore.

Variant C.
Add a hstore field in every parent table and forget additional tables.

I have no experience with hstore. 
What are the cons and pros of each variant? Which one would you choose? Can hstore baffle me with something strange?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I vote for the third option. The fewer tables the better sleep.

Hstore was invented for one-level parameter lists. It is stable, fast and simple, and perfectly fits your needs. I had similar task some time ago. I wrote an aggregate for easier conversion.

```
create or replace function hstore_add(hstore, text, text)
returns hstore language plpgsql 
as $$
begin
    return case
        when $1 isnull then hstore($2, $3)
        else $1 || hstore($2, $3) end;
end $$;

create aggregate hstore_agg (text, text) (
    sfunc = hstore_add,
    stype = hstore
);
```

I think it may save your time.

```
select kind, docid, hstore_agg(parname, parvalue)
from params
group by 1, 2
order by 1, 2;
```

Comment: Done! In development environment for now. It was easier than I could expect. Thank you all, especially klin for a time-saving code!

Answer (score 3):

If as you say you need to fetch the fields with the document then Denormalized hstore variant is better because the server will be able to fetch the entire document from a single location on disk instead of using several locations to index-join the document with the fields. The only problem I see with hstore is a somewhat unconventional syntax. Might be easier to work with JSON. PostgreSQL 9.4 will have an excellent support for [(indexed) binary JSON](http://obartunov.livejournal.com/tag/jsonb). Using binary JSON is [recommended](http://obartunov.livejournal.com/177670.html) by hstore authors, BTW.

So a plan might be to use a `json` column in 9.3 and then convert it to `jsonb` in 9.4.

Comment: For simple key/value pairs I think hstore is the better choice than JSON.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Technically hstore is no better than binary JSON and with JSON the client side might benefit from reusing the existing JSON libraries.