# PostgreSQL jsonb slower than hstore for large sets of key->value

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.6, nosql

I'm converting composite type into one of NoSQL types and have done performance tests for hstore and jsonb. For some reason jsonb gets slower the more key->value pairs there is.

My current type looks like this: `create type comp_type (key integer, value integer);`

It is stored in table as array `create table test_table (id serial, values comp_type[]);`

This is fine until I need to get rows that have certain keys in array of composite type and the only way to do this is to `unnest()` and that is expensive. So I have decided to migrate this data type into either hstore or jsonb as both of those provide operator that I need (`?|`).

hstore is both faster during seq scan and while using gin index. I admit that gin index on hstore is much more expensive than its equivalent for jsonb, but even then it is faster to just do seq scan on hstore than use index on jsonb.

This is how it looks on live demo: http://rextester.com/KPNQ26624

Actual data has much more key->value pairs, so performance degrades even more, to the point that jsonb is just worthless as simple key->value store.
Any ideas why this happens and how to fix?

Comment: I think it's quite natural, hstore is much simpler and for key/value objects should be faster than jsonb. [See also this post.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23628483/1995738)

Comment: @klin I understand that jsonb offers more and is also included by default, with is why I would prefer to go with it. It doesn't explain tho why jsonb is faster for smaller sets of key->value pairs. If you change in that live demo `generate_series(1,3000` to `generate_series(1,200` suddenly jsonb is 2x faster than hstore.

Comment: My opinion is based on practice, I often use hstore in my projects. One should analyse implementation details of both features to find the grounds of this behaviour.

Comment: you can call hstore a two dimension array. It is always key-pair array - right? While json is an "object" with unlimited recursive objects set as values against keys. I'd say it is natural that hstore serves better for array of key-pair, that's for it was made? and json just can be that as one of multiple other options. You don't ask why computing `::interval` is faster then converting text to numbers and then using formulas calculating interval. But you can use text for all values, but interval only for intervals. Sorry for such messy tirada.

Comment: @VaoTsun You are correct, hstore is one dimensional key->value store, while jsonb can be nested. However, `?|` operator says that it works only on `top-level keys`, so in that regard there is practically no difference between the two, as in both cases they just check for existence of top-level keys without caring what they contain. So as I understand this, there should be no performance difference or at least new-and-shiny jsonb shouldn't be outperformed by hstore. So maybe it is some kind of server setting that makes jsonb perform worse.

Comment: GIN indexes are created primarily for hstore I believe. They just support indexing jsonb by top keys. Try asking this question Oleg Bartunov and Teodor Sigaev - I can't think better persons to answer